# WP7 Application Certification Requirements

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need some clarification on the following [Windows Phone 7 Application Certification Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184843%28v=VS.92%29.aspx):

1. It is mentioned in the Application
   Certification Requirements that "The
   application must render the first
   screen with in 5 seconds after
   launch". What does that mean, either
   we need to display the splash screen
   with in 5 seconds or the home screen
   ?.
2. If the application finds that there
   is no data connection currently on
   the device, then can we show an
   error message in a message box saying "There is no
   data connection. Please check and
   launch the app again" and once the user dismisses the message box by clicking on the OK button, can we close the
   app?(this is what we do in our
   iPhone applications). Or do we have
   to show some old content, even if
   there is no data connection ?
3. In the Application Certification
   Requirements, it is mentioned that
   the application must not exceed 90mb
   of RAM usage. How do we check the
   RAM usage by an application ?

Please clarify the items mentioned above. Thanks!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I believe it's the first screen of your application, not the splash screen. This could include a loading screen (preferably with a ProgressBar) if you need to continue loading something. ([Related post](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/79285/480074.aspx#480074))

2) I've seen an app do exactly this. The user launches the app and if there's no connection, it displays a message and closes the app. As long as the user is aware that the app will shutdown because a data connection is required (but not found), it should be okay.

3) You can use [DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.applicationcurrentmemoryusage%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to check the usage. ([Example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941122%28v=VS.92%29.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, for question 1, it is a first screen (post splashscreen) must appears 5 sec after launch, and the application must be responsive after 20 seconds.